# TabIndex problem. Only getting a system beep

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008

Background: I've got a WinForm application with a ComboBox and a TabControl with two pages. On page one of the TabControl, I've got a FlowLayoutPanel containing about 10 Panels. Each of those Panels contain a Label and a TextBox. I'm using Visual Studio 2008 as my IDE.

Problem: I'm not able to tab between any of my controls. I go to View-Tab Order, and everything looks fine (although I know it's not). All I get is a system beep when I try to tab between controls.

Anyone else have a similar problem that they overcame? I'm sure I'm missing something really simple, but I don't know what it is. Is there a method to have Visual Studio rebuild the tab indexing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Instead of using Form.Show(), I used Form.ShowDialog(). Tabbing work correctly after that. Not sure why though.